# Responsive background photo

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have gone through all forums and tutorials available and can't seem to change the background of this into a photo, responsive if possible.
Here is a bit of the CSS, I'm clueless on this occasion.

```
body {
    font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #47a3da;
    background: url(images/1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Basically I want to add a responsive photo to this:
http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/NestedAccordion/

Comment: No idea what you want exactly.!

Comment: Sorry, define your problem with more details

Comment: I want a background image, reponsive on this site:

Comment: I want a background reponsive image on this site:

Comment: I want a background responsive image on this site, http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/NestedAccordion/, but the CSS I put doesn't work, I have no idea why. I don't know if it is because I m quoting the body instead of container, I don't know. Can you please help?

Comment: It's working. Check this fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/wrbth1h7/
Might be you put the wrong path  in css for the image.

Comment: Here is the full CSS:

Comment: where is CSS.? can't find.

Comment: I was not able to paste ok let's have a look

Comment: Yes I can see on dw it works but not live:

Comment: As I said in previous comment, It  might be possible that you have not set the image path properly in css. If your images are in image folder and css in css folder, then you need to specify the image path like this :  **../images/a.jpg** in CSS. As we can not help without knowing what went wrong.

Comment: No it is not this. But your code is working on dw but not live. On 2 different browser. No no problems with path at all.

Comment: Do I need a mark up on html or script?

Comment: Why does it show on live edit on dw and not live on the net?

Comment: Then can you show the code to put a responsive background photo?

Comment: Can you post directory structure of your files. ? Just to be sure if it is path or  something else.!

Comment: I can't add the whole CSS on the comment do you have an email or inbox? I ma new here

Comment: I can't chat on this as too new to site and not enough badges

Answer (score 1):

Try This : 
If your images are in image folder and css in css folder, then you need to specify the image path like this **../images-directory/imagename.jpg**

CSS

```
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #47a3da;
/*-----Double check path specified in CSS-----*/
  background: url(images/1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

You may check this URL if you want to see it live.  [www.coderomeos.org](http://www.coderomeos.org/)
we have set a background image which is repeated all over the body.

EDIT : Added Print screen of live website.
[image: Print Screen]

Do come back if you still face any issue.

Comment: Is this not the same? It surely still does not work for me:

Comment: Is this not the same? It surely still does not work for me: body {
    font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #47a3da;
/*-----Double check path specified in CSS-----*/
  background: url(body {
      font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
         color: #47a3da;
        background: url(http://http://blasonmoderne.com/Revenu_Positif_v5.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;

Comment: Can you just do it for me at this stage? Do you have an email I can send you the sheets?

Comment: It works! I have no idea why, so now how do I make this responsive and use photos I want. Do you think this is because we put this in the head rather than separate CSS sheet?

Comment: But then again it does not work with other site or photos from images folder!

Comment: It is no longer working, do you think I have some problems with DW or some kind of viruses or whatever?

Comment: it is only working with your code and the photo from that site. Why will it not work from any links?! And not my pics plus it does work on the mobile!

Comment: And again I link with images now changed the folder to image and it DOES NOT work!

Comment: Ok photo from image folder appearing but not appearing on mobile android LG phone

Comment: IT works! With photos now the folder is renamed but photos are not showing on Android LG mobile phone and I guess this us just a pic format

Comment: Now how do we make several photos rotate?

Comment: body {
    font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #47a3da;
    background: url(image/2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
 }